# Adding same "*.dll" reference to multiple projects in the same Solution

Tags: .net, dll, log4net, gac

I have a Visual Studio 2008 .NET C++/CLI Solution. My solution consists of many sub projects. I define a custom build directory for each project and called it "Output".

My solution:

- MyFirstProject (*.exe)
- MySecondPrject (*.dll)
- ...
- MyNthProject (*.dll)

Each of the sub project use Log4.net.So I create a directory (called LogBinary) and put log4.net DLL in that folder. Then to use log4net I add this DLL as a reference to each of my project.

But when I try to compile my main project (*.exe) I got tons of warning (over 400).

Just an example:

> *Warning  110 warning C4945: 'AbsoluteTimeDateFormatter' : 
>   **cannot import symbol from** 'somepath\log4net.dll': as
>   'log4net::DateFormatter::AbsoluteTimeDateFormatter'
>   **has already been imported from another assembly** 'log4net'"somepath\log4net.dll"*

Lots of warnings with:

> *has already been imported from another assembly*

Why do I get these warnings? Does anybody have a solution to add same DLL to multiple projects (except using GAC)?

Answer (score 5):

I finally found a solution to this problem which doesn't feel like a hack. I found the answer in [a response from 'pyro_serv` on the msdn social site](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/63efd1d6-bee1-4acc-95de-1f76a784d158):

> The fix is to use the "Use Dependencies In Build" and "Use In Build" flags on each VC project references (via the VC properties sheet), and toggle them as appropriate for your case to resolve this error.

So for the OP's example which looks something like this:

```
Solution -> Log4.net
Solution -> Proj1
Solution -> Proj1 -> Log4.net
Solution -> Proj2
Solution -> Proj2 -> Log4.net
...
```

The way to avoid the warnings is to set `Use Dependencies in Build` to false for all of the references to `Proj1,Proj2,..,Projn`.

I've just verified this with a demo solution and it works great - I can't believe how simple the solution is and how much time I've wasted to find it!

Comment: Just FYI, I recently had a similar problem stemming from "Use Dependencies" being set to True by default, except that in my case in addition to producing the warnings it was also producing C3699 `'^' cannot use this indirection on type 'x'` errors -- except that the types in question were managed types so it ought to have been able to do that.  Just in case anyone else encounters this little bit of weirdness too.

Comment: this. exactly the problem for me too on Visual-Studio-2005. Set `Use Dependencies in Build=false`, add the references and everything is fine. One may note that the `Use Dependencies in Build` doesn't even exist in newer VS version (2010 ...)

Answer (score 1):

Change reference on the projects, set all "copy local ..." properties to false.

Source : http://developertips.blogspot.com/2008/07/ccli-warning-c4945.html

Comment: Well this does not work...Have to also make "Use..." properties false for referenced *.dll..But in that situation you can not able to use that *.dll...It is not elagant solution but what i found is create an empty *.dll project add reference to that *dll(in my situation add log4.net dll to that dummy project).Then if wanted to use that dll(log4.net) from other project add that dummy dll project instead of direct reference to shared dll(log4.net)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem again today.
First of all, thanks to Jon Cage and the linked article in his post on this thread, [see above (or below)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12423588/2505186). +1!!! It solved my problem.

But because I hate things like `toggle them as appropriate for your case`, which means nothing but `trial and error`, I did some tests as I have 2 solutions with a good number of C++/CLI projects in each.

Here's my advice and explanation for it:
**For all 'self created' assemblies (that have 'copy local' set to true):**

> "Common Properties" -> "Framework and References" -> "References" -> Select a Reference.
> On the Property Sheet on the right -> "Build Properties" -> "Use Dependencies In Build"
> -- (copied from the linked msdn forum article of Jon Cage's post)

Set this parameter `Use Dependencies In Build` to "false" by unchecking.
It works as 'reference forwarding', see example below.

TECHNICAL BACKGROUND:
-> means 'references'
**method 1:**
in my solution SwCore:
A.1.1 `network->tools`, A.1.2 `network->basics`.
A.2.1 `tools->basics`.
A.3.1 `drives->basics`, A.3.2 `drives->tools`, A.3.3 `drives->network`
A.4.1 ...
with "Use Dependencies In Build" set to true, the reference A.1.2 can be omitted, as it is included in A.2.1.
all files are created in swcore\release\
== problem:
in solution DDI:
B.1.1 `DDI_hardware->DDI_job`, B.1.2 `DDI_hardware->drives`
B.2.1 `DDI_job->basics`, B.2.2 `DDI_job->tools`, `B.2.3 DDI_job->job`
`DDI_job` is created in DDI\Release\ and with "U.D.InBuild" set to true, it includes `basics`.
`DDI_hardware` is created... and with "U.D.InBuild" set to true, it includes `DDI_job->basics`.
DDI_hardware also references basics from SwCore\Release\
**==>> double reference to basics and others. VS sees 2 files and can not realize that it is the same content.**

**method 2:**
A.1.1 `network->tools`, A.1.2 `network->basics`.
A.2.1 `tools->basics`.
with "U.D.InBuild" set to FALSE, the reference A.1.2 can NOT be omitted, because it is not forwarded from A.2.1.
**== works, because no assembly will contain other deeper dependencies, so there won't be conflicts.**

BTW: This forces you to specifiy all necessary references for each project, so you also have an overview what you are using in your project.

Last info: I can not tell for sure, if my explanation is correct. Maybe s.o. else can confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem.
It is caused by the following situation, where a project depends on another project:

```
my_solution -> System.Xaml.dll -> System.dll
my_solution -> System.dll
```

When I removed the reference to System.dll (for instance) it solved the compiler warning.

Comment: That doesn't work if you have (say) 2 mid-hierarchy projects which need access to leaf projects. When the mid-level projects are included you get the main project whining that the symbols have already been included by one or the other.

Comment: no need to down-vote it when you didn't provide a solution yourself. After years of this build warning, at my work we have simply turned off build warning 4945 as being completely useless.

Comment: But you don't have the exact same problem; the OP says that all of his component .dlls also reference the dependant project and if that's the case, what you've posted won't solve his problem. If you can post an answer as to how to disable the warnings then I'd happily upvote that...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same warning on this situation:

```
Solution:
 |
 |-> Project1 : Outdir = "C:\out"
 |
 |-> Project2 : Outdir = [default Outdir] // Was wrong in this case
 |
 |-> Project3 : Outdir = "C:\out"
```

The dependencies relations were the following ones.

```
Solution -> Project1
Solution -> Project2 -> (Project1)
Solution -> Project3 -> (Project1, Project2)
```

Fixing Project2 Outdir to "C:\out" (as actually intended, it was a newly created project and forgot to change it) fixed the warning.